# SQL Select Statement comparing wrong values

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

```
SELECT ABC, 123 FROM TABLE WHERE ABC != "123"
```

I'm using SQLite and trying to select values from a table where the abc column doesn't contain the values '123'. It's not working as the != statement is not looking for the value '123' under ABC but is comparing the value of the '123' column instead.

What I want it to do is retrieve ABC and 123 of where the cell of ABC does not contain '123'

Comment: Are you using double quotes or single quotes? Your sample code is using double quotes but your description is using single quotes. It matters. One denotes objects and the other denotes strings. And if you're looking for a numeric value, you don't need quotes of any kind at all.

Comment: Haveyou figure it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got it right, you have a table with both 'ABC' and '123' columns, correct?

To search for rows where the ABC column does not contains the '123' value, you would use a query like this:

```
SELECT ABC, 123 FROM TABLE WHERE ABC NOT LIKE '%123%'
```

Or, in case you want exclude only perfect matches, in other words, you only don't want the rows in which the ABC column corresponds exactly to '123', you can use:

```
SELECT ABC, 123 FROM TABLE WHERE ABC NOT LIKE '123'
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace double-quotes with single:

```
ABC != "123" -> ABC != '123'
```

SQLite as many other databases use single quotes for string literals and double quotes for identifiers. So "123" is interpreted as a column name and '123' as a string.